# Mac crashes when I'm using Visual Studio Code + Chrome

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

Since the Catalina update in May, whenever I'm using Visual Studio Code for an extended period of time, upon saving my work my laptop crashes, saying there has been an error. On reboot, I get the message below. As you can imagine, this are not ideal working conditions! I called Apple Support last week and we ran several diagnostics and reinstalled the OS. Then I updated, uninstalled, and reinstalled Visual Studio Code (the update didn't fix the problem, obviously reinstalling didn't either). It's a MacBook Air 2017, running Catalina 10.15.5.

Any insight as to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800b44aa3a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8e8c5bcb, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000172164124, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x013050217a000004, RBX: 0xffffff80232a8800, RCX: 0x000c6e6300000000, RDX: 0xffffff80f50f8000
RSP: 0xffffff913d60b930, RBP: 0xffffff913d60b960, RSI: 0x000c6e6300000013, RDI: 0xffffff8020849000
R8:  0x00000000000c6e62, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000020000011000, R11: 0x00000000075f0001
R12: 0xffffff80f5861030, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff80232a8e50, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff7f8e8c5bcb, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff913d60b390 : 0xffffff800b31f5cd 
0xffffff913d60b3e0 : 0xffffff800b458b05 
0xffffff913d60b420 : 0xffffff800b44a68e 
0xffffff913d60b470 : 0xffffff800b2c5a40 
0xffffff913d60b490 : 0xffffff800b31ec97 
0xffffff913d60b590 : 0xffffff800b31f087 
0xffffff913d60b5e0 : 0xffffff800bac27cc 
0xffffff913d60b650 : 0xffffff800b44aa3a 
0xffffff913d60b7d0 : 0xffffff800b44a738 
0xffffff913d60b820 : 0xffffff800b2c5a40 
0xffffff913d60b840 : 0xffffff7f8e8c5bcb 
0xffffff913d60b960 : 0xffffff7f8d94c51e 
0xffffff913d60b9a0 : 0xffffff7f8d94ca4f 
0xffffff913d60b9d0 : 0xffffff7f8d95b67d 
0xffffff913d60ba10 : 0xffffff7f8e8cbbdc 
0xffffff913d60ba40 : 0xffffff7f8d94a00b 
0xffffff913d60bac0 : 0xffffff800ba5695e 
0xffffff913d60bb10 : 0xffffff800ba54be7 
0xffffff913d60bb60 : 0xffffff800ba5dcb3 
0xffffff913d60bca0 : 0xffffff800b4082b2 
0xffffff913d60bdb0 : 0xffffff800b325328 
0xffffff913d60be10 : 0xffffff800b2fbcc5 
0xffffff913d60be70 : 0xffffff800b312aa2 
0xffffff913d60bf00 : 0xffffff800b430d05 
0xffffff913d60bfa0 : 0xffffff800b2c6226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f8d943000->0xffffff7f8da06fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[E35D090D-DB9E-3DD0-9723-651FA730AA13]@0xffffff7f8bd87000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f8bf01000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f8d082000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f8d8c9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[1FB49168-0280-3F04-A99A-F830C915E994]@0xffffff7f8be2f000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics(14.0.6)[6139D437-2098-316E-967B-4692BAA82C5B]@0xffffff7f8e87e000->0xffffff7f8e917fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f8bf01000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[F1E7389D-2807-3C5D-8A7F-5422542E867F]@0xffffff7f8d082000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f8d8c9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.5.4)[D695D9DA-7C20-35D6-910F-E7A332A0F515]@0xffffff7f8d943000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Adobe CEF Helper

Mac OS version:
19F101

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
Kernel slide:     0x000000000b000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800b200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800b100000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 102061375115602
last loaded kext at 101877780985322: >!UAudio   323.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8eab4000, size 434176)
last unloaded kext at 102028841625416: >usb.!UHostCompositeDevice   1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8d937000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.2.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.2.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.2.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.2.26
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphics    14.0.6
>!AHDA  283.15
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ALPC  3.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.6
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.4
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ASSE  1.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>!AHSSPISupport 59
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Comment: It drives me nuts when one of Apple Support's first tool they reach for is "reinstall the OS."  It sends a message that "this OS is so flaky that we need to reinstall it so we can be sure the right pieces and parts are there."  If anything, they should have started you off in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  But looking at the crash log, it identified a particular daemon:  `Adobe CEF Helper`.  I would disable or uninstall the Adobe stuff first and see if the issue gets resolved.  Give those two options a try and post your results.

Comment: Allan thank you so much! After about 24 hours that seems to have worked!

Comment: Post what you did to solve it and ping me in comments again so I can up vote!  I'm more than happy to get you some reputation points so you can participate more here on Ask Different!

Comment: @Allan thank you! What I did to resolve this issue was simply to update Adobe Creative Suite. It had been running in the background without me noticing, and since the OS update there had been a conflict. Once I ran the update, no more crashes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I’ll go ahead and write up an answer so you can mark it as “solved” so it doesn’t remain open indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

> I called Apple Support last week and we ran several diagnostics and reinstalled the OS

Apple “support” is notorious for doing this, they run a couple diags, most likely a memory test and a disk drive test on for those things to come back “ok” so they figure “just reinstall the OS like it came from the factory. If it works there, they’re happy with it.

> I updated, uninstalled, and reinstalled Visual Studio Code (the update didn't fix the problem, obviously reinstalling didn't either)

VSCode is used extensively on Mac’s without problem so immediately  pointing to it is like saying your car keeps stalling so a) replace and reinstall the motor and b) stop carrying thise groceries from that popular store in your trunk.

#### Diagnostics

Before reinstalling the OS, start off with Safe Mode.  It disables all 3rd party apps, kexts (drivers) and daemons (background processes) do you’re only running “pure” macOS.  IF the problem goes away, it’s something that’s being loaded.

**A little deduction**

Thanks to the log you posted, we can see that a daemon `Adobe CEF Helper` seems to be causing issues.  I would start by uninstalling or disabling Adobe and see how things work out (judging from the comments, you found the problem and fixed it!)

Going forward, if you run into something like this, always start in Safe Mode to help eliminate problems.  Reinstallation is usually the last thing you should do when diagnosing a problem

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment?

Answer (score -1):

Disable GPU acceleration with -- flags when starting chrome based gui software, search for current **chromium** flags with GPU in name.
Start the app from terminal within .app dir /Applications/SomeApp.app/Contents/Mac../binary_name --flagName

iGPU is causing problems here and there but a kernel panic is unusual. What's your mac hw?

Comment: What makes you think I downvoted you?  Your answer is incorrect  (if you read the comments you’ll see I solved her issue), but I definitely didn’t  down vote you.